# I am having 10 lines in a file. Now I need to print first 3 lines then lines 5-7 and then lines 9-10. What's the LINUX command for this?

Tags: linux

cat f1.txt
aman
vishal
ajay
jai
vijay
rahul
manish
shobhit
kritika
tavleen
Now output should be as per the above given conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can have a counter in file reading loop and print it,

count=0

while read line
do
   let count++
   if (count == 1) //likewise use it
   then
     echo $line
   fi
done

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`: use `-n` to print only selected.

```
sed -n '1,3p' file
sed -n '5,7p' file
sed -n '9,10p' file
```